# error while installing seaborn using pip and conda in jupyter notebook/terminal

Tags: pip, seaborn, jupyter, conda

I'm working in a jupyter notebook, and I'm trying to install seaborn using the following code:

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} seaborn
```

But I get this error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [45], line 2
      1 import sys
----> 2 get_ipython().system('conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} seaborn')
...

File ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Documents/Course-Programming/Machine-Learning/Projects/sample-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py:57, in ProcessHandler.sh(self)
     55     self._sh = pexpect.which(shell_name)
     56     if self._sh is None:
---> 57         raise OSError('"{}" shell not found'.format(shell_name))
     59 return self._sh

OSError: "/bin/fish" shell not found
```

I tried installing it using pip from my terminal, as well as removing /bin/fish from etc/shells but nothing changes. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the conda environment, then recreating it with seaborn as one of the packages, like this:

```
conda create --prefix ./env pandas numpy matplotlib jupyter scikit-learn seaborn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not working in virtual environment then try these steps:-

1.) Go to Anaconda Navigtor
2.) Select Environment in Navigation panel.
3.) In base root, change filter option installed to non installed.
4.) Search Seaborn
6.) If its not installed then installed it

Comment: Thank you, Nadeem Ashraf. Removing the conda environment and reinstalling it with seaborn as a package worked for me.